# Converting the heic to JPG and get file location

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I'm trying to upload the multiple Images to backend, but backend that I'm working with doesn't support heic format for the image. So I want to convert those heic images to JPG and upload it with the file location. I'm using below method to upload the images from the fileURL.

```
func uploadTask(with request: URLRequest, fromFile fileURL: URL) -> URLSessionUploadTask
```

I'm using PHAsset to get the fileURL.

1) So how can I convert the heic image to JPG with loosing any quality and get the file location?

2) If we convert the heic image to JPG will it increase the size of the image?

Comment: What’s wrong when you create an image from it? Just save the jpeg representation of that image.

Comment: The way StackOverflow works is that you show us the code that you've written trying to fix your problem and we can try to help you find a solution. The important part is that you have to try to do it yourself first (and show us what you've tried). Like Leo said, have you tried creating a `UIImage` and then getting the `JPEG` data from it?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the solution. When we get FileURL from PHAsset, if Image is HGIC you can convert it into UIImageJPEGRepresentation and get the data. Then you can use below method to upload data

```
func uploadTask(with request: URLRequest, from bodyData: Data) -> URLSessionUploadTask
```

If it's JPG you can use fileURL(you can use this for any fileURL as long as your backend support that file format, In my case backend doesn't support HGIC format, So I had to convert it into Data)

```
func uploadTask(with request: URLRequest, fromFile fileURL: URL) -> URLSessionUploadTask
```

There are some drawback when we convert HGIC to JPG or PNG::

1) Over here when we convert HGIC image to JPG, CPU and Memory Usage will be higher.

2) When you convert the image, size will be higher. For example conversion at 1.0(Highest- maximum Quality) can increase the file-size(JPG file) up-to 30-35%